# How do I properly mince garlic?

Tags: garlic, knife-skills, cutting, knife-safety

I often need to mince garlic to add to any number of dishes. If I don't want to use a garlic press or microplane, how do I mince it with a knife?  What type of knife should I use and how should I cut it?  I'm most interested in the techniques associated with efficiency and safety.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to treat it as a really, really small dice if you have a sharp enough knife.

But it's easier to use a chefs knife to cut it in one direction, and then try to start cutting it into sticks .... but when it starts getting difficult, just rock your knife back and forth, slowly moving it through the pile.

After a while, turn your knife (or the board) 90 degrees, and rock it some more.  As the pile starts spreading out, use your knife to pull it back into a tighter pile ... and keep rocking and turning until it's down to the size you want it.

...

If you're going to be using it right away, you can also give it a quick crush before mincing -- but this damages cell walls differently than cutting, and can cause some chemical reactions that change the flavor (the intensity fades quicker).