# How do I properly mince ginger?

Tags: knife-skills, cutting, ginger, knife-safety

I often need to mince ginger to add to any number of dishes.  If I don't want to use a microplane, how do I mince ginger with a knife? What type of knife should I use and how should I cut it? I'm most interested in the techniques associated with efficiency and safety.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost exactly like [mincing garlic](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/74898/67), but you want to make sure that the first cut is across the fibers of the ginger.  (you'll be cutting it into coin-like shapes)

... and then julienne what you can, and start the rocking to chop it up as fine as you want it.

Comment: Who is this julienne you speak of?

Comment: @dpollitt :  julienne == cutting into matchsticks.

Comment: You might also like cutting it in half down the middle first, so you have a flat side to put face down and it can't roll around as you cut the coins, especially if your knife isn't super sharp or you're not as comfortable yet.

Comment: @Jefromi Please use comments to ask for more information or to suggest improvements. Short answers as comments are generally discouraged at SE. Plus I'd like to vote on your contribution. Thx

Comment: @dpollitt It *is* a suggested improvement. It's just a slight modification to the technique.

Answer (score 1):

First wash the ginger thoroughly and peel the skin off. You can use your regular peeler or knife too. Knife is better since much of the ginger is not wasted this way. Just work your knife with slight pressure on the skin of ginger in a upward motion and the skin will get scraped off. Now cut the ginger into chunks first, and then proceed with mincing. Hold a piece and start chopping it finely. Then club them together and work with your knife randomly on them if you want still finer bits. This method always works for me.

Comment: oh, right ... peeling.  You can also peel with a spoon -- using the same scraping method.  You want a fairy thin spoon -- if it's too heavy, the edge might be rounded over too much